# Single zipWith not executed

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using the following code, but `completable` inside `zipWith` not executed, but the function inside `zipWith` is called.
I have tried to convert the `compltable` to `single` but it is not executed too. what i have missed?

```
 public Completable fun() {
        return single1().zipWith(single2(),
                (singleResult1, singleResult2) -> completable.execute(singleResult1, singleResult2)).ignoreElement();
    }
```

Comment: What does `completable.execute` return? What do you do after calling `fun()`?

Comment: execute return `completable`(i mean service.execute return `completable`),i am subscribing to `fun` in my fragment

Comment: I see that `zipWith` return` Single<Completable>` not sure i choose the right way but it is the closest that I found to combine result of 2 `singles` and return `completable`

Comment: I need something like flatMap but with the result of the two singles`

Comment: Have you looked at the available `flatMap`s?

Comment: single1().flatMap give 1 result, i need to combine both results in one place

Comment: @akarnokd or you mean flatMap after zipWith?

Comment: Oh thanks, I was need to add .`flatMapCompletable(completable -> completable)` at the end of the chain.